# Why can't I make a generic struct and a trait's generic method work together?

Tags: rust, traits

I have a question about Rust traits. I have the following:

```
pub trait SelectAsDsl: Sized {
    type Output;

    fn select_as<SQ>(self, subquery: SQ, alias: String) -> Self
    where
        SQ: AsExpression<SQ> + SingleValue + SqlType;
}

#[derive(QueryId, Debug, Clone)]
pub struct SelectAs<SQ> {
    subquery: SQ,
    alias: String,
}

impl<T> SelectAsDsl for SelectAs<T> {
    type Output = Self;

    fn select_as<SQ>(self, subquery: SQ, alias: String) -> Self
    where
        SQ: AsExpression<SQ> + SingleValue,
    {
        SelectAs {
            subquery,
            alias,
            ..self
        }
    }
}
```

This gives an error "expected type parameter `T`, found type parameter `SQ`" in the trait implementation when returning the struct, but when naming them the same, the compiler complains that the name is already in use.

When changing it to create a void struct and returning self, the compiler gives no error.

```
impl<T> SelectAsDsl for SelectAs<T> {
    type Output = Self;

    fn select_as<SQ>(self, subquery: SQ, alias: String) -> Self
    where
        SQ: AsExpression<SQ> + SingleValue,
    {
        let _ = SelectAs { subquery, alias };
        self
    }
}
```

How is this caused and how should I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no connection between the struct's `SQ` and the trait method's `SQ` (except they share the same name, of course). The fact that they share the same name is just confusing. `select_as()` should return `Self`, which is `SelectAs<T>` in the context of the `impl` you showed, but it returns `SelectAs<SQ>`.

The fix is obviously to make it returning `SelectAs<T>`. Since it needs `subquery` to be of type `T`, that means we need to declare it so. This is a bit problematic since the trait (where we declare it) does not have access to `T`. So we should declare `T` (or `SQ`) as a parameter of the trait instead of the method (maybe even an associated type):

```rust
pub trait SelectAsDsl<T>: Sized {
    type Output;
    fn select_as<T>(self, subquery: T, alias: String) -> Self
    where T: AsExpression<T> + SingleValue + SqlType;
}

impl<T> SelectAsDsl<T> for SelectAs<T>
{
    type Output = Self;

    fn select_as(self, subquery: T, alias: String) -> Self
    where T: AsExpression<T> + SingleValue + SqlType
    {
        SelectAs {
            subquery,
            alias,
            ..self
        }
    }
}
```